# Definition of the derivative of a Poisson structure on a manifold given by bivector called a Poisson bivector

Tags: poisson-geometry

What is the derivative of  a Poisson structure on a manifold  given by a Poisson bivector?

Comment: Is this term used anywhere, or should an answer invent a definition? On an *orientable* manifold you have the modular vector field $\Phi$ = $\pm$ the divergence of the Poisson bivector field $\pi$ [[Poisson Structures](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642310898), §4.4.3].

Comment: In coordinates, applying \partial_k to the bivector  \Theta^{ij}\partial_i\partial_j is no problem. How to say it coordinate free?

Comment: @JimStasheff: Hi Jim! Actually, the coordinate expression is unhealthy because it will not look like a partial derivative hitting the Poisson bivector in any other coordinate chart. You could put a connection $\nabla$ on the tangent bundle (e.g. a Levi-Civita one) and replace $\partial_k\to\nabla_k$. But it's unclear what problem that solves for you. (Perhaps a symplectic connection is more natural, if the Poisson structure is of maximal rank.)

Comment: Thank you - very very helpful comments

Comment: Since I first asked, I discovered the derived bracket version {f,g} = [[Theta,f],g]